# What are the handles/wheels called when making a homemade vise (like a moxon?)

Tags: tools, terminology

I would really like to make my own vises, like moxon, tail vise, etc.  I'd love to be able to afford the benchcrafted kits but they are price-prohibitive.  I've seen people make them out of press vises, but I'm looking for a much larger handle than comes with standard press vises, as I figure that the larger the rotational diameter, the more torque one might apply to the vise screw.  However, I am not getting a lot of hits when I search for "bench screw wheel" or "bench screw handle."

Is there a specific name for the type of handle I am referring to?

[image: Picture of Benchcrafted tail vises without price]

Comment: "crank" would be the word I'd use

Comment: Ah!  I didn't even think about crank!  My search begins anew!

Comment: "hand wheel", see below answer!

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, they're called "hand wheels"; [this](http://lumberjocks.com/projects/79379) lumberjocks post talks about how this person made a vise and called them hand wheels.  Searching for hand wheels brings up results.